# Question on .asec (encryption) on Froyo 2.2 / installing app onto sdcard

Tags: android

I installed my app on the emulator with 2.2 and onto the sdcard. When I browse via adb shell, I can see that the encrypted app file lies under /mnt/secure/asec/com.myapp-1.asec but it also lies as plain apk file unencrypted at /mnt/asec/com.myapp-1/pkg.apk as well and I can do a 'adb pull' without special permissions and unzip it to see it's content.

Unfortuntately my N1 is in repair and I cannot check on a real device right now - but wondering, why can I still access the plain apk so easily (at least on the emulator)?

(Not sure if this question is supposed to be asked on StackOverflow or on ForceClose.com, but I figured it's more related to development and how to secure/encrypt your app as a developer, therefore I'm posting it here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer from the Android dev mailing list:
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_frm/thread/f7d11237744fe5fa/0e92cb2905632408#0e92cb2905632408

> Apps on SD card are stored in an
>   encrypted container for platform
>   security purposes -- so that other
>   applications can not modify or corrupt
>   them.  When mounting the SD card,
>   these containers are mounted so that
>   they can be accessed in the same way
>   as apps stored in internal storage.

Thanks to Dianne Hackborn/hackbod